# Why have an abstruse function instead of a straightforward function?

Tags: javascript, function

I simplified this abstruse function model of a function (log1) that I got from somewhere.  I've looked at anonymous functions and closures, and I don't see that these apply here.  Is there any advantage of the abstruse function vs. a straightforward function (log2).  Would somebody expound on why one would use the log1 model?  And, how does "log1" get to be a global name?

The functions accumulate texts in a div reserved for them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!-- HTML5 -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>..</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() { // this is obviously the abstruse model
  this.log1 = function(txt) {
    var divid = document.getElementById("log1id");
    divid.innerHTML += "<br />" + txt;
    };
  })();

function log2(txt) { // this is obviously the straightforward model
  var divid = document.getElementById("log2id");
  divid.innerHTML += "<br />" + txt;
  };

window.onload = function() {
  log1("Message one");
  log2("Message one");
  log1("Message two");
  log2("Message two");
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
body
<div id="log1id">--Log1:</div>
<div id="log2id">--Log2:</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is very common to wrap JavaScript in `(function() { /* your code */ })();`. There are many advantages to this practise.

Comment: @Marty - can you be more specific?

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: In strict mode, `this.log1` will fail since *this* will be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Not in this case, no. They are equivalent. However, if you do this:

```
(function() {
  var divid = document.getElementById("log1id");
  this.log1 = function(txt) {
    divid.innerHTML += "<br />" + txt;
    };
  })();

var divid = document.getElementById("log2id");
function log2(txt) { // this is obviously the straightforward model
  divid.innerHTML += "<br />" + txt;
};
```

then they do differ: the second version will pollute the global environment with `divid`, while the first one will not.

Given that they are evaluated in the global environment (where `this` is the global object), both functions are global. `log2 = ...` is equivalent to `this.log2 = ...` in absence of `var log2`, and nothing changes `this` in the case of `log1`, so they both assign a function to a property of the global `this`.

Answer (score 1):

The "abstruse" version does the same exact thing. The only difference being that anything declared inside the bounds of the structure

```
(function() {
})();
```

only is in scope inside the structure. This is called an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), and provides a really good way to implement encapsulation in javascript.

So if `log1` wasn't a property of `this` you wouldn't be able to call it.

In a larger project that spans multiple files, you might accidentally use a variable/overwrite a variable from another file. A good way to prevent this is to wrap the body of the whole file in an IIFE.

Comment: `divid` is already out of the global scope.  It's inside the function.  Your IIFE explanation is a general explanation, but does not actually do anything useful in the OP's specific example and it does make the code more obtuse than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks -- Searching "javascript iife" returns MONTHS of reading!  I confirm @RobG 's note that "in strict mode, this.log1 will fail since this will be undefined."  This blows my mind.  Doesn't this shoot down the whole concept of using (function(){ })(); ?

Comment: @dcromley Most times you are using an IIFE for encapsulation; thus, creating a property on `this`, which would put it in the global scope is pointless. It is important to note that `this` actually refers to `window` in this context, which you can confirm for yourself by typing `this` into your browser's javascript console. So instead of `this` you could use `window.log1`, or alternatively you could create a global variable outside the IIFE like `var self = this` and then use that inside the IIFE.